# PHP Get id's from items in XML string

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xbrl

I want the id of every context item in the following XML string.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" id="xbrlID" xmlns:eba_met="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/met" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:eba_dim="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dim" xmlns:eba_MC="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dom/MC" xmlns:eba_PL="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dom/PL" xmlns:eba_BA="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dom/BA" xmlns:eba_BT="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dom/BT" xmlns:eba_CT="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dom/CT" xmlns:eba_SC="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dom/SC" xmlns:find="http://www.eurofiling.info/xbrl/ext/filing-indicators" xmlns:eba_AS="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/dom/AS" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.eba.europa.eu/eu/fr/xbrl/crr/fws/finrep/its-2013-03/2014-07-31/mod/finrep_con_ifrs.xsd"/>
  <xbrli:context id="context">
    <xbrli:entity>
      <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://scheme">31489</xbrli:identifier>
    </xbrli:entity>
    <xbrli:period>
      <xbrli:instant>2014-12-31</xbrli:instant>
    </xbrli:period>
    <xbrli:scenario>
      <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba_dim:APL">eba_PL:x26</xbrldi:explicitMember>
      <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba_dim:BAS">eba_BA:x7</xbrldi:explicitMember>
      <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba_dim:MCY">eba_MC:x111</xbrldi:explicitMember>
    </xbrli:scenario>
  </xbrli:context>
  <xbrli:context id="context_2">
    <xbrli:entity>
      <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://scheme">31489</xbrli:identifier>
    </xbrli:entity>
    <xbrli:period>
      <xbrli:instant>2014-12-31</xbrli:instant>
    </xbrli:period>
    <xbrli:scenario>
      <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba_dim:APL">eba_PL:x26</xbrldi:explicitMember>
      <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba_dim:BAS">eba_BA:x7</xbrldi:explicitMember>
      <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba_dim:MCY">eba_MC:x99</xbrldi:explicitMember>
    </xbrli:scenario>
  </xbrli:context>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

I'm able to parse the XML with the following lines of code;

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmldoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace("xbrli", "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance");
$nodelist = $xpath->query("/xbrli:xbrl/xbrli:context");
```

However when I foreach the nodelist and print every node, no identifier is displayed. Is there any way to retrieve the id of every context block from the XML? e.g. context, conext_2, etc.

Comment: Can you state what output is coming and what you expected?

Comment: You don't display identifiers in your example (which is otherwise pretty much totally correct). So what is your question? The foreach you write (and ask about) sadly is not part of your question so it's not clear what you exactly ask about and where you probably made a little mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/@attribute_name` to select node's attribute in xpath :

```
$idlist = $xpath->query("/xbrli:xbrl/xbrli:context/@id");
```

Or using `getAttribute("attribute_name")` while looping list of `<context>` node :

```
foreach ($nodelist as $node){
    //do something useful with $id    
    $id = $node->getAttribute('id'); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `->getAttribute()` since you already got the nodes correctly, just iterate and point it to the node and use the method:

```
foreach($nodelist as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('id');
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rqjBI0)

`->evaluate` will work as well:

```
foreach($nodelist as $node) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(./@id)', $node);
}
```